# Intersecção entre Listas (Arrays)

Tags: python, array, matemática, set

Eu estou desenvolvendo um código para fazer o cálculo do MDC (máximo divisor comum) entre 2 números.

Eu consegui decompor os números em fatores primos, gerando assim uma lista (array) para cada de números primos.

A solução final seria extrair um novo array com a intersecção entre os 2 arrays da decomposição dos números e calcular o produto entre seus itens. No entanto, não estou conseguindo fazer isso.
Tentei fazer pelas técnicas de conjuntos (set), mas não deu certo:

```
   conj1 = set(list1)
   conj2 = set(list2)
   conj_inter = conj1.intersection(conj2)
```

Segue o repositório no GitHub: https://github.com/rigueti-bruno/Projetos_Python/tree/main/calcular-mmc-mdc

Alguém teria alguma dica de como eu poderia resolver isso?

Answer (score 1):

O que exatamente não deu certo? Seja mais específico. Esse trecho está funcionando devidamente, ele devolve a intersecção de dois conjuntos. Aliás, se não quiser usar o método `intersection`, há o operador `&` que também devolve a intersecção de conjuntos.

De qualquer modo, não gosto desse jeito. Converter para conjuntos pode comprometer a ordem dos elementos (conjuntos são estruturas não ordenadas); se a ordem for importante no seu caso, já é inviável usar essa abordagem.

Um laço encadeado já resolveria seu problema:

```
lista1 = [1,2,3,4]
lista2 = [3,4,5,6]
intersec = []

for item in lista1:
    if item in lista2 and item not in intersec:
        intersec.append(item)
```

Claro que é mais sofisticado se usarmos uma *list comprehension*:

```
intersec = [x for x in set(lista1) if x in lista2]
```

Aqui foi necessário converter para conjunto para garantir que não houvesse duplicatas. Se você puder garantir previamente que não há duplicatas em pelo menos uma das listas, pode iterar sobre ela sem fazer a conversão, o que preserva a ordem dos elementos. Se tiver como saber de antemão qual a menor lista, também poderá preferir lançar sobre ela a iteração (menos tempo de execução).

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua contribuição Bernardo! Ela contribuiu para desvendar um pouco mais o meu quebra-cabeças!

Comment: Mas, o que eu ainda preciso é que, por exemplo, se eu tiver 2 arrays assim: a = [2, 3, 2, 2] e b = [2, 2, 5] o array de intersecção fosse [2, 2]  - que o produto seria 4, exatamente o MDC entre 24 e 20. Mas, seja com a conversão em Set ou com o laço que você sugeriu, os valores não se repetem.

Comment: Eu adaptei o laço que você sugeriu à minha aplicação e gerou o mesmo resultado que a conversão em set - você pode verificar o código no link para o GitHub acima.

Comment: @BrunoRiguetiBrandão, as respostas elas são dadas apenas com base nos dados que apresentou na pergunta e não em links externos. Pelo que foi informado na pergunta essa resposta está correta. O que alegou precisar no [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/548519/intersec%c3%a7%c3%a3o-entre-listas-arrays/548538#comment979733_548538) é diferente do que perguntou. Minha sugestão, como são problemas distintos seria melhor abrir uma nova pergunta para esse problema do comentário. Veja [ask] e [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387)

Comment: @BrunoRiguetiBrandão respondendo brevemente sua pergunta. Se o seu objetivo é encontrar o MDC entre dois números, sua lógica está equivocada. Para isso, você terá que implementar o algoritmo de Euclides, que não tem nada a ver com isso que você está fazendo.

Comment: Bom dia Bernardo! Consegui concluir meu algoritmo e a versão final passou em todos os testes. Pode conferir no meu GitHub.

Comment: Segue o link com a versão final do meu código: https://github.com/rigueti-bruno/Projetos_Python/blob/main/calcular-mmc-mdc/03-mdc-v4.py

Comment: Python calcula nativamente o [Máximo Divisor Comum](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/math.html#math.gcd)